# SQL How to drop dynamically named Foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a foreign key constraint on a table using the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableWithForeignKeyConstraint] WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PrimaryTable])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PrimaryTable] ([Id])
```

The name of the foreign key constraint is dynamically generated and thus has a name on the production server that I can't predict (I have no access to the production server).

Now I have also created a new table `NewPrimaryTable` and I want the tables with the foreign key constraint to drop that constraint and create a new one to `NewPrimaryTable`.

Comment: You could do something like this to list the foreign keys: `SELECT t.name AS table_name, f.name AS foreign_key_name FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys f ON f.parent_object_id = t.object_id;`

Comment: Yet another reminder why you should always name your constraints....

Comment: Add a bit of dynamic SQL to that @RichardHansell and I would suggest you have an answer for the OP. :)

Answer (score 1):

@Richard Hansell set me on the right path, I am now using the following query to find the name of said foreign key constraint:

```
SELECT fk.name
FROM
    sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables parent_tables ON fk.parent_object_id = parent_tables.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns parent_columns ON fkc.parent_object_id = parent_columns.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id = parent_columns.column_id
INNER JOIN
    sys.tables referenced_tables ON fk.referenced_object_id = referenced_tables.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns referenced_columns ON fkc.referenced_object_id = referenced_columns.object_id AND fkc.referenced_column_id = referenced_columns.column_id
WHERE parent_tables.name = 'TableWithForeignKeyConstraint'
AND referenced_tables.name = 'PrimaryTable'
AND parent_columns.name = 'ForeignKeyColumn'
AND referenced_columns.name = 'Id'
```

Also I strongly agree with Zohar Peled to always name your constraints.